# При загрузке страница показывает сразу iframe

Tags: html, iframe

При загрузке страница показывает сразу iframe. Есть html страница и в ней iframe. Когда я обновляю/загружаю страницу, она автоматически прокручивается до iframe. Как решить?

Comment: код страницы с проблемой в студию

Comment: Url страницы имеет подстроку вида #id? id - это id фрейма или элемента близкого к нему. Браузер автоматически перепрыгивает к элементу заданному таким образом в url.